# Candidate set generation in Apriori algorithm

Tags: java, apriori

I am trying to implement Apriori algorithm in Java, and have problems with generating Candidate itemsets. To create candidates for k-itemset I use all combinations of k-1 and 1-itemsets. For example, for
Frequent 1-itemset:
bread:9, milk:9, coffee:9, sugar:10.

Candidate 2-itemsets generated should be: bread milk, bread coffee, bread sugar, milk coffee, milk sugar, coffee sugar.

But my code returns: bread coffee, bread milk, bread sugar, coffee bread, coffee milk, coffee sugar, milk bread, milk coffee, milk sugar, sugar bread, sugar coffee, sugar milk (all permutations; returns both bread milk and milk bread, however, these two are the same thing).

My code:

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getCandidates(Map<String, Long> one_itemset_1, Map<String, Long> n_itemset_1){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tuples = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    
    Map<String, Long> one_itemset = sortbykey(one_itemset_1);
    Map<String, Long> n_itemset = sortbykey(n_itemset_1);
    
    for(String item : one_itemset.keySet()) {
        
        for(String item2 : n_itemset.keySet()) {
            if(!item.equals(item2) && !item2.contains(item)) {
                ArrayList<String> singleList = new ArrayList<String>();
                singleList.add(item);
                String item2_sep[] = item2.split(" ");
                for(int i = 0; i < item2_sep.length; i++)
                    singleList.add(item2_sep[i]);
                //singleList.add(item2);
                tuples.add(singleList);
            }
            //index2++;
        }
        //index2 = 0;
        //index1++;
    }
    
    return tuples;
}
```

Is there a way to modify this method to get rid of repetitive itemsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apriori algorithm does not require you to do a join between Lk and all 1-itemsets to get Ck+1. This approach will have a much higher runtime. Rather we join Lk with itself under the condition that the first (k-1) elements are the same in both the k-itemsets: [see here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/apriori-algorithm/)

As for having duplicate items in your code, you could just define an ordering in the 1-items (`I1` < `I2` < `I3` ... `In`) and then only consider the items in ascending (or descending) order. This will keep the itemsets sorted -> (`I1`, `I3`, `I5`) is a valid itemset but (`I1`, `I5`, `I3`) is not.

This can be easily done with two for loops for your example:

```
for (int i=0; i<k-itemsets.size()-1; i++){
    for(int j=i+1; j<k-itemsets.size(); j++){
        // compare k-itemsets here and join in ascending order to produce k+1-itemset
    }
}
```

I would also advise you to go through other sources if you do not understand the algorithm at first. For e.g., [the SPMF library](https://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/index.php) has the implementation of most popular algorithms related to pattern mining.